# google cloud storage public url, to use in img src

Tags: google-cloud-storage

first, i have read, searched google and everywhere. but i cant find the solution to my problem. I can upload images to my google cloud storage bucket. then, i want to get the public URL, so i can save it to my mongodb, and access it later on for my site.

I have a code here, written in GO.

```
// profile func, that receive filename, and file
name, self_link, err := google_storage.Upload(handler.Filename, file)

// then after acquiring the self_link, i update the user
db.UpdateUser(session_id.(string), db.UserUpdate{"ProfileImage": self_link})
```

the problem is, i can't access the file from my link to my pages when passing it to the html..

i guess, my links aren't public?

here is my oauth config

```
config := &oauth.Config{
    ClientId:     clientId,
    ClientSecret: clientSecret,
    Scope:        storage.DevstorageFull_controlScope,
    AuthURL:      "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    TokenURL:     "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    TokenCache:   oauth.CacheFile(cacheFile),
    RedirectURL:  "https://www.example.com/oauth2callback",
    AccessType:    "offline",
}
```

from there after authorizing my web server, i can just

```
// my object setup
object_to_store_data := &storage.Object{Name: fileName}

result, err := service.Objects.Insert(bucketName, storage_data).Media(file).Do()
```

any help is appreciated, im new to google cloud storage, and go.

thank you in advance

Comment: You need to set the ACL on the object to `publicRead`. See the `predefinedAcl` field on [objects.insert](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert).

Comment: hey, thanks for the suggestion. I will try that now. currently, i was reading to signed URL. getting the signed url, then saving it for later access.

Comment: hello, im still not good in golang. but how do i set my Acl to my object? i have 
object_to_store_data := &storage.Object{Name: fileName}
ill edit my post

Comment: its really frustrating, was able to figure out setting, the Acl, but now, googleapi: Error 400: Required, required.. error message with nothing helpful. figuring this since yesterday, read the documents, examples and maybe everything. still i cant get a public access.

Comment: For which call/code are you getting this 400 error? Also, we have an example of setting an ACL for an existing object in Go here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-go-samples - does that code no longer work?

Also, if you want this for every object in the bucket, consider instead setting the Default Object ACL property of the bucket - in which case every object will have the ACL upon creation, and you won't have to have this separate call to change the ACL anyway.

Comment: Zach, thank you so much. got it now working, it took me almost 2 days,  and slept at 3am figuring this. i did not have Entity and Object in my &storage.ObjectAccessControl. ill update my post